# XML Files are Unable to Reference class Files

Tags: java, android

Since about a week ago android studio is breaking almost all code I write because of certain critical issues that there's not a ton to find online about. The one I'm trying to find a solution for is that xml files, whether  it's the AndroidManifest.xml file or the activity files are erroring on the classes.

I tried using the alt+enter and having it auto fix it by creating a new file under the same name of the file that already exists and for under a second the error goes away only to error again. I have reinstalled android studio in a attempt to see if I somehow corrupted files.

The only code I have written is for 2 buttons. So unless I'm doing something very wrong, I'm unsure how the code in the class could cause this. under the "tools:context" field it errors on the file saying that the class file is not recognized(in the xml file).

MainActivity:

```java
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void Options_Button1(View view) {
        Intent option = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Options.class);
        startActivity(option);
    }
    public void Add_Button1(View view){
        Intent add = new Intent(MainActivity.this,placeholder.class);
        startActivity(add);
    }
}
```

activity xml file:

````java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="Options_Button1"
        android:text="@string/options6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="304dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="Add_Button1"
        android:text="@string/add6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: Check if activity is inside a package!

Comment: Unfortunately,I had it in a package so the app could adapt to different screen sizes. I deleted all the other sizes and the issue is still present. Thanks though.

Comment: One more thing you can do here , delete .MainActivity inside tools:context and then start typing name of the activity it will reference activity automatically.

Comment: It does find the activity, it changes it to the extended file location of the class file but then proceeds to error on the ".MainActivity".

Comment: You can try rebuilding your project. Going to Build => Rebuild Project or clean project Build=>Clean Project

Comment: I tried the Build=>Rebuild route and that ran the build again and it looked like it was going to work, but there was some updates going on and after those completed, the ".MainActivity" errored again.

Comment: You can also try going File=>Invalidates Caches/Restart. And if this doesn't work you can create a new project :).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm somewhat new to android studio and didn't know it stored cached files. It fixed all my other errors as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was, as mentioned in the comments of the post above, clearing cached files through file=>invalidates Caches/Restart.